# Linux kernel process limits

Tags: recursion, process, linux-kernel

Could Someone please explain how the linux kernel handles a ballooning process queue?

I am implementing a recursive fibonacci program that for fib(n) spawns 3 processes:

add(fd1, fd2)

fib(n-1) (stdout piped to fd1)

&fib(n-2) (stdout piped to fd2)

with the base cases of course...

but as n approaches 20 or so, some of my fork()s are raising errno 11 and fib is not returning the correct value

from ~$man fork

```
   EAGAIN fork() cannot allocate sufficient memory to copy the parent's page tables and allocate a task structure for the child.

   EAGAIN It was not possible to create a new process because the caller's RLIMIT_NPROC  resource  limit  was  encountered.   To
          exceed this limit, the process must have either the CAP_SYS_ADMIN or the CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capability.
```

If I implement a jump statement to try the fork() again in the event of this error, though, the process will eventually terminate with the correct value for fib(~20)

I understand that if I did fib(700) it would probably not terminate, but I am interested in what is happening right at the fringe of when fork() system calls start raising this error.

Comment: What kind of info are you looking for ? All that's really happening is that the OS notices it can't create any more processes, and makes fork() return an error instead of creating a new process.

Comment: The internal data structure that the kernel uses to manage the process queue, and why would forcing a loop eventually causes termination and correct output?

Comment: I'm guessing that the focus here is on the forking and not so much the actual computation, but just in case: there are iterative algorithms that would avoid this issue entirely.

Comment: Have you been able to document the sequence of forks that get executed, identifying which succeed and which fail?  I'd think that would be at least somewhat enlightening.

Comment: @Kdawg I don't know what your loop actually does, but if one of your existing child processes finishes and exits, there's new resources available to create more processes.

Comment: Yes I am thinking now that the forks() eventually work because other processes hit their bases cases and terminate, freeing up memory for subsequent forks.

Comment: But the kernel must keep a data structure of process control blocks for context switches. What is the logic that limits the size of this data structure? Are limits based on total size, percentage allocated to a single user...